# How to remove .php extension from url which file name have dash(-)?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Using following .htaccess rule I can easily remove .php extension from the url which file name start with : index.php, account.php, login.php etc

But

If the file name start with e.g : how-to-work.php **(note the dash)** thne it's not removing the .php extension from the url.

Can you tell me how I can do this ?

**.htaccess file :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Opps! It's working now :)

Comment: One more issue : Now it's showing the file name without any .php extension but when I can click on logo I mean home page It's showing ' www.myurl.com/index '. Is it possible to show : www.myurl.com only ?

Comment: It's working fine for me.